# App Cold start or App Lauch times are increased in lollipop compared to kitkat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Most of the app cold start values are regressed in lollipop stock android compared to kitkat stock android builds.

We recorded using camera and observed all the apps are launching 20% more time in lollipop stock android compared to kitkat stock android.

what changes casing these regression in lollipop ? how to fix this issues?